# Closed form solution for t-stats and p-values in multiple regression

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, p-value

I am trying to build a spreadsheet that will perform multiple linear regressions on a number of data series using the closed-form solution. It was fairly straightforward to write the solution for the coefficients. However, I also need to obtain the t-stats or the p-values in order to evaluate the statistical significance of the coefficients.

**What are closed-form solutions for t-stats and/or p-values?** I did some research on the web but haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Excel has the `TTEST` function

Comment: As your inability to find simple formulas might suggest, for p-values such niceties don't exist in general (well, for small degrees of freedom they do but generally you're not dealing with 1 or 2 or even 5 d.f.).

Answer (score 2):

I believe Excel has built in functions to calculate these (see [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Run-a-Multiple-Regression-in-Excel) for example).  Is there a reason are you trying to do it manually?  The general form for testing regression coefficients is $t$ =$\hat{\beta}\over{se(\hat{\beta})}$.  The p-value can then be obtained by comparing the value against the standard t-distribution.

Comment: Can you perhaps provide the explicit formulas for $\hat \beta$ and its standard error? This would answer the question then.

Comment: The formula sfor $\hat{\beta}$ and the standard errors are in hundreds of posts on this site.